# Surefire - Maven error

Tags: maven, jboss, jboss7.x

Hi guys when i run Maven Install i got that erros on Surefire-Reports.

I'm whatched this video on youtube: JBoss Fuse Getting Started Home Loan Demo Part 1 
Author: Christina Lin

I dont know u solve this errors :s

In surefire-reports folder i have that files:

File1:
http://pastebin.com/5zxjwFBK

File2:
[http://pastebin.com/NN6tEN16](http://pastebin.com/5zxjwFBK)

Can someone help me solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your  test *com.tutorial.homeloan.RouteTest*  It looks like there is a mock setup that is never called but expected to be called.  Update the mock to be more lenient, so that it is not expected to be called (if that leaves the test still valid).  This is done in different ways depending on the mocking framework being used.